# Only enable jQuery UI sortable for items that contain a known child

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

The [example](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items) works fine, but the problem is when I want to enable sortable only for items that have a child that contains a known class (e.g. `action-move`).

I have this HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="page-item item">
            <a class="text" href="#">Test 1</a>
            <div class="actions">
                <div class="action-move"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item item">
            <a class="text" href="#">Test 2</a>
            <div class="actions">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item item">
            <a class="text" href="#">Test 3</a>
            <div class="actions"><div class="action-move"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My current code is:

```
$(".nav").sortable({
    items: "li .action-move"
});
```

But I guess this selects `.action-move` elements.

I want to only enable sortable for the first and last item (the items that contain `.action-move` element).

How can I do this?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hX8K/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.has](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to filter elements with certain descendant elements

```
li:has(.action-move)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use first last child?

```
:first-child
:last-child
```

Comment: This doesn't answer to the question. My question is clear: *Only enable jQuery UI sortable for **items that contain a known child***.

Comment: I know that, but your solution is not general, it will work only for my example.